# ¿Como puedo comentar una linea de código en sublime text 3 en lenguaje html?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Quiero comentar una linea de código en **html** con el programa **sublime text** 
Seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: te refieres a los métodos abreviados de teclado?

Comment: los comentarios en html son : `<!-- este es un comentario -->`

Comment: Si te refieres a los cometarios en HTML, Shassaim te dio la respuesta. Si en cambio es un atajo de teclado, es CTRL+Ç

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola te comento que con sublime text, al menos en windows la forma de hacerlo es al inicio de la línea elegida que quieres comentar:

Presionando Ctrl + Tecla que tiene el símbolo de llave que cierra "}" al mismo tiempo, una vez que ya tienes seleccionada dicha fila.

Te pongo el siguiente ejemplo, mira como la última línea p la he comentado y por ende no saldrá en el navegador

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A eius obcaecati, distinctio veritatis ipsam ullam! Hic, assumenda voluptatem cumque, velit voluptate corporis officia cum, perspiciatis libero tempora laboriosam possimus magni!</p>

  <a href="#">A ningún lado</a>
  <!--<p>Hola a todos</p>--> <!--esta es la línea comentada-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

En los teclados extendidos **Ctrl+/** y **Crtl+Shift+/** pero en la laptop... pues no se puede entonces se lo tiene que configurar en: **Preferences->Key Bindings — User** y agregar dentro de los corchetes:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } }, 
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
```

Dónde puedes modificar las teclas de atajo de teclado en lugar de **ctrl+/** y **ctrl+shift+/** respectivamente. Espero les sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Si te refieres a los métodos abreviados de teclado, solo en windows. Les sumo esta solución practica.

La respuesta de jhon chacolla tiene la ventaja que sirve para todos los lenguajes.
Osea, sin importar el lenguaje de programación, comenta la linea o varias, según lo seleccionado.

Pero tiene una pega. En sublime text 3 no funcional las teclas para comentar y des-comentar código fácilmente.

En Stack Overflow encontré la solución:

Ir a `Preferences->Key Bindings - User` y pegar lo siguiente:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
```

Para probarlo, selecciona el texto, y presiona simultáneamente <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>.
Y listo, a disfrutar!
La solución fue reemplazar el métodos abreviados de teclado por defecto <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>. Por <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>, que es la misma tecla en el teclado.

Este bug esta [reportado](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11157&start=0)

Answer (score 1):

en mi caso active ambas opciones

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } ,
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay otro modo para escritorio , <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>
La tecla que pone ? debe contener el símbolo /
igualmente.Saludos